# Example of isomorphic sheaves whose sections aren't isomorphic

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Are there examples of sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ such that $\mathcal{F} \cong \mathcal{G}$ but it is not necessarily true that $\mathcal{F}(U) \cong \mathcal{G}(U)$ for every open set $U$? I was sure there are, since a surjective morphism of sheaves doesn't always induce a surjective morphism of sections for every open set. However, I'm having a hard time coming up with examples.

If the answer turns out that no such examples exist, my next question would be whether or not a natural isomorphism of functors $F: A \rightarrow B$ and $G: A \rightarrow B$ would imply that $F(X) \cong G(X)$ for every object $X$?

Comment: The [*definition* of a natural isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Definition) is a natural transformation such that all the morphisms $\eta_X\colon F(X)\to G(X)$  are isomorphisms.

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathcal F\cong\mathcal G$?

Comment: A possible source of confusion here is that while injective, surjective and bijective morphisms are defined as those which have the corresponding property on stalks, this is not the case for isomorphisms (although, depending on what your sheaf is a sheaf of, this may be equivalent). However in any case a bijective (on stalks) morphism always corresponds to bijective maps $\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(U)$, so we do not have the behaviour that surjective morphisms may exhibit

Comment: ^ In fact it doesn't depend on what your sheaf is a sheaf of; if a morphism of sheaves induces isomorphisms on stalks (– note, this is not used as the _definition_ of an isomorphism) then the morphism is indeed an isomorphism in the senses defined in Mark Kamsma's answer. This addresses the substance of your question if we substitute your usage of ‘isomorphism’ by “morphism which induces isomorphisms on stalks”. The reference for this given in related questions on here is Hartshorne 2.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible definitions for *natural isomorphism*. For a natural transformation $\eta: F \to G$, both of the following statements make sense.

1. Every arrow $\eta_X: F(X) \to G(X)$ is an isomorphism.
2. There is a natural transformation $\theta: G \to F$ such that $\eta \theta$ is $Id_G$, the identity natural transformation on $G$, and $\theta \eta = Id_F$. In other words: $\eta$ is an isomorphism in the functor category where $F$ and $G$ belong to.

These two are equivalent. The direction $2 \implies 1$ is easy, for every $X$ we directly see that the inverse of $\eta_X$ is $\theta_X$. For the converse, $1 \implies 2$, there is only one sensible candidate for $\theta$. Namely we take $\theta_X$ to be $\eta_X^{-1}$, the inverse of $\eta_X$. We only need to check that $\theta$ is then indeed a natural transformation. So let $f: X \to Y$ be any arrow. Using naturality of $\eta$ we get
$$
F(f) \theta_X = \theta_Y \eta_Y F(f) \theta_X = \theta_Y G(f) \eta_X \theta_X = \theta_Y G(f).
$$
It might help to draw the relevant picture if the above is confusing.

So in particular, whenever two sheaves $F$ and $G$ are isomorphic through a natural isomorphism we get that each $F(U)$ and $G(U)$ are isomorphic for every $U$. You mention that an epimorphism of sheaves is not always componentwise surjective. An isomorphism is a very special kind of epimorphism, namely a [split epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+epimorphism). A split epimorphism of sheaves is always surjective on every component (nice exercise).

Comment: Thank you very much, this answers my question perfectly.

Comment: @nolatos Great to hear :) Can you accept the answer, that way the question won't appear as "unanswered" anymore.